# How to calculate cycles /issue for floating point additions for 1 core?

Tags: cycle, flops

(Not Homework!!)
This is my processor :
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz

Number of cores : 2

I was reading FLOPS I came across a questions that asks calculate cycles /issue for floating point additions for 1 core.(I know the number of cores I have)
Should I study the architecture of my machine and calculate the cycles???)

I am not sure what is an issue(an instruction??), and how would you calculate the cycles?
I would appreciate it if someone could hint me in on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Intel Optimization Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html) without SIMD instructions it should be 1 cycle/issue

[image]

Intel Core i5 is based on Intel microarchitecture code name Westmere (06_25H, 06_2CH and 06_2FH), which supports SSE. With SSE instructions you should get double throughput, and if it supports VXA you would get 4x.

Comment: No problem, but review the manual... Probably you can find more details on that